# How to add a library/module to a project using a gradle task?

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The idea is to be able to add libraries to a project without actually modifying the code. This is mainly to be able to generate builds as per requirements. While I could achieve this with buildFlavors, I wanted the flexibility of being able to do this for any number of libraries.

Basically its something like this,

- I have a base app
- One team developed a library A
- I have another library B
- One client needs only library A, another needs both A and B. Down the line other clients could need different libraries.

What I need is to add these libraries to the Base App and generate builds as per requirements.

For this, I created the following task. For the moment I am just trying with local modules already registered in `settings.gradle` file, but not added to the project

```
val myArg: String by project
//use task in this way - gradlew addDependencyAndGenerateBuilds -PmyArg dependency name
tasks.register("addDependencyAndGenerateBuilds"){
  doLast {
    if(project.hasProperty("myArg")){
      dependencies.implementation(dependencies.project(":$myArg"))
    }
    finalizedBy("clean", "build")
  }
}
```

Now if I run this task - `./gradlew addDependencyAndGenerateBuilds -PmyArg libraryA`, I get the following error,

```
Task 'libraryA' not found in root project
```

What I need is for this `libraryA` to be added to the base app and new builds generated accordingly.

Comment: "One client needs only library A, another needs both A and B. Down the line other clients could need different libraries." -- by "client", do you mean something like "customer"? If so, then product flavors is what I would use, with one flavor per customer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, "customer" is what I mean. But I do not want to create a new flavor for each new customer. I want to be able to do this on the fly, without doing any change in the code. Just to clarify, these libraries will be developed in such a way, that the application code wouldn't need any changes to access library features. 

That is why I tried to write a gradle task to add libraries on the fly and generate build with those libraries included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an issue with run task command. There needs to be an `=` between `myArg` and `libraryA`.

The full command is like this,

```
./gradlew addDependencyAndGenerateBuilds -PmyArg=libraryA
```

While this fixed the issue mentioned (i.e. Task libraryA not found..), it failed to build with some errors.

I then scrapped the whole idea and just added an extension method in the app gradle.

```
fun DependencyHandlerScope.addExtension(extensionsFilePath: String) {
  val extensionsFile = File("${project.rootDir}", extensionsFilePath)
  if (extensionsFile.exists()) {
    val extensions = extensionsFile.readBytes().decodeToString()
    val extensionsJson = Gson().fromJson(extensions, JsonObject::class.java)
    if (extensionsJson.has("modules")) {
      println("Adding module dependencies")
      extensionsJson.getAsJsonArray("modules").forEach {
        implementation(project(it.asString))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is used in the dependencies block like this,

```
dependencies {
  ........
  ........
  addExtension("extensions.json")
}
```

This method takes in a Json file containing a list of dependencies and then just adds them to the project. All one had to do is then edit this json file before generating a build.

To further simplify this, I just added a task that edits the json file,

```
val myArg: String by project
tasks.register("addNewExtension") {
  doLast {
    val extensionsFile = File(
      "${project.rootDir}",
      "extensions.json"
    )
    val extensionsJson = if (extensionsFile.exists()) {
      val extensionsData = extensionsFile.readBytes().decodeToString()
      Gson().fromJson(extensionsData, JsonObject::class.java)
    } else {
      JsonObject()
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("myArg")) {
      val modules = extensionsJson.getAsJsonArray("modules") ?: JsonArray()
      if (!modules.contains(JsonPrimitive(":$myArg"))) {
        modules.add(":$myArg")
      }
      extensionsJson.add("modules", modules)
    }

    extensionsFile.delete()
    extensionsFile.createNewFile()
    extensionsFile.writeBytes(extensionsJson.toString().toByteArray())
  }
}
```

You could then run - `./gradlew addNewExtension -PmyArg=libraryA`, followed by a `./gradlew build`.
This will then update the json, and then generate a new build with the library included.